# Does there exist any simply connected domain which is not convex?

Tags: complex-analysis

Does there exist any simply connected domain which is not convex?

I find difficulty to distinguish between them. Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "I find difficulty to distinguish between them" Hmmm... What are these definitions already?

Comment: Tomar tak fatabo. Besi pondit mone koro naki nijeke?

Comment: ?? $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plenty: how about the interior of a [pentagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagram)? Or the "banana-shaped"
region where you take the set difference of a pair of open discs of the
same radius with close centres? Or more prosaically, the complex
plane with the non-positive real axis removed?

Comment: But in many of the complex analysis books they are used as convex sets when proving Cauchy's integral formula.